# How to set ng-disabled in AngularJS when input is decimal

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, how do I set `ng-disabled` property in the button so that it won't be enabled when the user enters a decimal input?

Currently, the box is highlighted in red when I entered "0.1" but the button is enabled.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="person.age" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Age" 
    class="form-control" min="0" ng-change="compute()" ng-required="!person.age">

<button id="ok-btn" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="okEdit(person)" 
    ng-disabled="(!person.age && person.age !== 0)">OK</button>
```

Comment: when person.age= undefind? and person.age !==0?

Answer (score 1):

Check if `person.age` value is equal to parsed value, like that:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.person = {};
  $scope.isDisabled = function(person) {
    return parseInt(person.age) !== person.age
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="number" ng-model="person.age" name="age" placeholder="Age" class="form-control" min="0" ng-required="!person.age">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="okEdit(person)" ng-disabled="isDisabled(person)">OK</button>
</div>
```